# Capturar valor de un select con un ciclo for en php

Tags: php

Tengo un código que, aunque se ve bastante sencillo, no logro detectar dónde está la falla o qué estoy haciendo mal. Debo capturar el valor del select ya que me servirá para ingresar el dato en una tabla.

```
<label>Edad Representante</label> 
<select name="edadRepresentante">
<?php
    for ($i=18; $i <101 ; $i++) { 
       echo "?><option value=$i>$i</option><?php";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, vamos por partes.

Aunque no has mostrado exactamente la estructura de tu código, se puede suponer que estás usando una página que tiene una estructura `HTML`.

Así que cuando cargas esa página en un navegador, el navegador lee la estructura `HTML`, en primera instancia, y la representa para que el usuario pueda verla. En javascript, por ejemplo, se le llama a esto `DOM` ( Modelo en Objetos para la Representación de Documentos ) aunque al ser un modelo de representación que se usa en `HTML` y `XML` también puede ser usado en PHP mediante librerías especificas para dicho caso como `PHP-DOM.`

**Entonces, hasta este momento tenemos dos cosas en mente:**

**1.** Que toda página web debe tener una estructura que no es mas que unas instrucciones, etiquetas en la mayoría de los casos, que dicen como es la página y que va en cada cosa.

**2.** Que alguien debe tomar esa estructura y representarla, ósea convertirla, en una interfaz para que un usuario la pueda ver e interactuar con la misma.

Aquí es donde se complica un poco el asunto.

Existen varias maneras de hacer el punto 1 y el punto 2. Entonces, vamos analizar que puede aplicarse para el presente caso:

Punto 1: Existen varias formas de generar la estructura de una página web. Se puede hacer mediante a) `HTML` ó similares, en b) `HTML` con PHP añadido, pero también se puede hacer mediante c) `PHP` en estado puro.

Entonces, el navegador espera que alguien le envíe esa estructura para representarla pero el navegador está en el computador del usuario.

Cuando se trata de `HTML` el navegador recibe ese `HTML` y lo representa el computador de un usuario.

Pero cuando encontramos código `PHP` la situación cambia porque ese código, esas instrucciones en `PHP`, se deben ejecutar primero en un servidor y ese servidor luego le envía al navegador el resultado de dicha operación.

Osea que cuando ves algo en `HTML` ves una interpretación de unas instrucciones en tu navegador.

Y cuando ves PHP estás viendo ya el resultado de una operación que un servidor X realizó antes de que tu pudieras representarla en tu navegador.

A lo anterior se le llama Lenguaje al lado del cliente y Lenguaje al lado del servidor. `PHP` es del lado del servidor porque se ejecuta en el servidor que estas consultando y no en tu ordenador.

Si quieres crear un sitio web y este sitio web tiene partes en HTML y dentro de este código `PHP` debes tener en cuenta que `PHP` se ejecuta muy rápido, mucho antes de que se cree la representación (DOM) para las instrucciones `HTML`.

Entonces cuando ves tu navegador el DOM ya fue representado y lo que estás haciendo, entonces, es crear nuevas instrucciones PHP sobre algo que ya fue creado y representado de la misma forma que si pintaras un paisaje en un lienzo y, dos meses después, intentarás crear un árbol nuevo, puedes pintar un árbol encima pero no será parte de la pintura original porque dicha pintura fue creada dos meses antes.

- `PHP` se ejecuta.
- Posteriormente se representa `HTML.`

Cuando creas un bucle for dentro de una estructura `HTML` en realidad estás ejecutando un código `PHP` antes de que se represente el `HTML`, por tanto, no creas elementos de interacción con el usuario porque el `HTML` aún no ha sido representado y no te queda otra que imprimirlo en la página web.

Por consiguiente, no puedes luego pretender que vas a interactuar con elementos creados por `PHP` como si fueran elementos `HTML` porque dichos elementos en `PHP` fueron creados antes que cualquier cosa y no fueron representados dentro del DOM en tu navegador y solo puedes interactuar directamente con lo que puedes representar en tu navegador. De la misma manera que si preguntaras pidieras a alguien que te dijese un número y te respondiera con el número 4. Puedes usar el número 4 pero no sabes realmente como hizo la persona para llegar a ese número, pudo haber sumado el 3 y el 1 o sencillamente multiplicar 2 x 2. Tu no lo sabes porque eso no está en tu navegador por lo que no puedes interactuar con eso.

¿A que vamos con todo esto? que tu bucle `FOR` está imprimiendo algo dentro de una estructura `HTML` que ya está representada en tu navegador pero no creando apartes nuevas de dicha estructura por lo que solo puedes interactuar con la estructura que forma parte del `DOM` y solo puedes recoger datos de una estructura representada en tu navegador ya que cuando interactuas con un `SELECT` estás haciendo como un usuario en un navegador.

**Ante esto existen varias soluciones:**

**1.** Usar elementos de la página web que contengan acciones que permitan llamar a nuevas páginas web en las cuales le solicite o le envíe información x por medio de `GET` o `POST.`

**2.** Usar lenguajes de programación que permitan interactuar directamente con el `DOM` como `javascript` para insertar elementos nuevos mediante llamadas `AJAX` ó similares.

Pero me temo que PHP por si mismo no podrá servirte para capturar el valor del Select por lo explicado anteriormente, así que tendrás que buscar como generar, cargar y obtener información de manera dinámica en `PHP` o, lo que es lo mismo, como usar `PHP` con otros lenguajes como Javascript conjuntamente.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo como puedes obtener la edad que has seleccionado mediante tu option. En tu código tienes el fallo en te `echo`.

As introducido el cierre y apertura de la etiqueta `php` y el segundo error es qué no has concatenado tus variables `$i`

> Te dejo un **ejemplo** completo, obteniendo el valor seleccionado:

```
  <?php
        //Reseteo.
        $msg = $tu_seleccion = NULL;

        if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
            //Obligatorio selección.
            if (empty($_POST['edadRepresentante'][0])) { 
                $msg = "Debes seleccionar tu edad.";
            } else { 
                //Obtenemos el dato del option seleccionado.
                $tu_seleccion = $_POST['edadRepresentante'];
            }


            //Verdadero selección.
            if ($tu_seleccion) {
                //Ya puedes guardar la edad en tu Base de datos
                echo $tu_seleccion; 
                //Sentencia SQL.

            }

        }

        //Error.
        echo $msg;


    ?>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label>Edad Representante</label> 
        <select name="edadRepresentante">
            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
        <?php
            for ($i=18; $i <=100 ; $i++) { 
               echo "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $i . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

Con JQuery + ajax + PHP puedes realizar esto de manera relativamente sencilla, mira este ejemplo usando un documento .html y otro .php por separado pero ambos juntos en la misma carpeta:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Hola</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(Principal);
function Principal(){
    var options = "";
    for (i=18; i <101; i++) {        //Este es el mismo ciclo for que tenias para generar las edades
     options+="<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";  //se generan las options con las edades
  }
    $("#laID").html(options);        //le inserto todas esas options al select creado en el body

    $("#laID").change(function(){    //Cuando selecciones alguna de esas edades
        var edad = $(this).val();    //capturo ese valor
    var datos = {laedad:edad};       //lo almaceno en un Java Object Literal Notation
    $.ajax({                          //para poder enviarlo por ajax
      url:"test2.php",               //al documento test.php
      type: "POST",                  //por el método POST
      data: datos                    //y con esos datos.
      });
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="edadRepresentante" id="laID">
        <!-- Aquí se autoinsertarán las options generadas con el ciclo for de arriba-->
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que hicimos fue generar el select con todas las opciones de edad y cuando tú selecciones cualquiera de esas edades, enviará ese valor al siguiente archivo:

**test.php**

```
<?php 

$edad = $_POST["laedad"];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

$ponga = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `representantes`(`edad`) VALUES (:edad)");
$ponga->bindValue(':edad',$edad,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ponga->execute();

echo $edad;

 ?>
```

Entonces hemos recibido la edad seleccionada y la hemos insertado en una supuesta base de datos llamada "test", en una tabla llamada "representantes".

**nota:** hemos usado PDO para hacer esa inserción a una base de datos mysql.

Comment: Hola cuando me refiero a una tabla era a la tabla en la base de datos no una tabla en HTML, disculpa si no fui especifico

Comment: Aún te sirve si te doy un ejemplo con jquery?

Comment: Claro, lo que sirva para mejorar y aprender es válido.

Comment: @shadowmors he editado la respuesta, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score -2):

Esto es imposible, PHP es un lenguaje **SERVER SIDE** se ejecuta antes de que puedas ver en pantalla el resultado; el script termina para cuando el usuario puede interactuar con este campo.

Necesitas un `form` que apunte a un script PHP, cuando le den `submit` a ese `form` llamará al script de PHP y ahí tendrás el resultado en:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

Nota: **NUNCA** olvides escapar los inputs.

Comment: no entendí muy bien, me quedo la duda por que yo puedo hacer esto y los datos si me los toma: <label>Profesion del Representante</label>
  <select name="profesionRepresentante" id="profesionRepresentante">
   <?php
   include "conexion.php";
   $sql = "select id_profesion, profesion from profesiones order by profesion";
   $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

   while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
    echo "<option value=$reg[0]>$reg[1]</option>";
   }
   mysqli_close($conexion);
   ?>
  </select><br><br>

Comment: ¿Quieres *capturar* un valor o *imprimir* un valor en pantalla?
 Porque el código que proporcionas usa `mysqli_fetch_array` que **toma** datos de una base de datos MySQL y los imprime cuando usas `echo`.

Comment: Buenas, quiero obtener su valor para almacenarlo en una variable que usare en una tabla, realmente no quería colocar todos los option, hasta llegar a los limites de edad, por eso se me ocurrió hacer un ciclo.

Comment: El valor lo tienes en la variable `$i` y puedes (si es necesario) meterla en un array para tener un array con números del 18 al 101 pero no tiene mucho sentido si me preguntas; después puedes usar el array en donde quieras. Si lo que quieres es **obtener** el valor que el **usuario final** va a seleccionar con el mouse o teclado entonces como ya lo comenté antes, **es imposible** ya que PHP termina su ejecución antes de ser enviado al usuario para que pueda verlo.

Comment: Lo siento mucho, ya que estaba trabajando, excepto que el $ _POST [], no estaba donde debería estar